# Auto Update value in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a component with auto-updating value based on cookies:

```
let cookies = 0;
(function count() {
cookies = document.cookie.split("?");
setTimeout(count, 10);
return cookies;
})();


class CartButton extends React.Component {
    state = {quantity: cookies.length}
    render() {
      return (
        <Cart onClick={e=>{show_cart()}}>
    <Mfont>{this.state.quantity}</Mfont>
    <Icon>shopping_cart</Icon>
    </Cart>
      );
    }
  }
```

'count' function works as expected, component is rendered with the latest value returned. Unfortunately, it does not auto-update when 'cookies' are changed. It returns this error:

> Warning: render(...): Replacing React-rendered children with a new root     component. If you intended to update the children of this node, you should    instead have the existing children update their state and render the new components instead of calling ReactDOM.render.

I have tried various variations here but still can't figure it out :/

Comment: Do you have a sandbox/fiddle/codepen for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidMount` will get execute only once when your component loads first time. This is the correct place to write any logic which we need to execute after page load.

Try this,

```
class CartButton extends React.Component {
    //It is good to have a constructor for the component which has state
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {quantity: cookies.length}
      this.updateQuantity;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.updateQuantity = setInterval(()=> {
        cookies = document.cookie.split("?");
       this.setState({quantity: cookies.length})
      },10)
    }
    //Don't forget to clear any setInterval like below
    componentWillUnmount(){
       clearInterval(this.updateQuantity);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Cart onClick={e=>{show_cart()}}>
          <Mfont>{this.state.quantity}</Mfont>
          <Icon>shopping_cart</Icon>
        </Cart>);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here your `CartButton` is not updating even though count is working fine because `CartButton` is not listening to your `cookies` variable. React component updates only when there is either `props` or `state` change.
You can something like this..

```
class CartButton extends React.Component {
    state = {quantity: cookies.length}

    componentDidMount(){
      setInterval(function count() {
        cookies = document.cookie.split("?");
       this.setState({quantity: cookies})
      }.bind(this), 10)
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Cart onClick={e=>{show_cart()}}>
          <Mfont>{this.state.quantity}</Mfont>
          <Icon>shopping_cart</Icon>
        </Cart>);
    }
  }
```